# GDB find value within memory

Tags: search, memory, int, find, gdb

I am having trouble with the find command in gdb. What I am trying to do is, finding a specific value e.g. (964) within the memory of a process. I have been successfull but my solution takes way to long!

What I did:

```
cat /proc/16617/maps
```

Than getting the libc_malloc parts, I know the value is within those.

```
7e43c000-7e451000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:libc_malloc]
7e452000-7e45b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:libc_malloc]
7e470000-7e47c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:libc_malloc]
7e47d000-7e490000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:libc_malloc]
7e4cc000-7e4dc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [anon:libc_malloc]
```

Than I could use the examine command to investigate each value. This one is working but it takes so much time. I guess the find command within gdb is way faster doing this.

```
0x78b0e070: 0   829055599   57  59
0x78b0e080: 2   2024857820  2024857860  2024857900
0x78b0e090: 1970810756  4587520 71  0
0x78b0e0a0: 0   2024857756  2024857756  0
0x78b0e0b0: 0   27  1970675312  1
0x78b0e0c0: 1   2024857728  0   43
0x78b0e0d0: 23  23  0   1936029041
```

E.g addresses do not match due to several runs, but it is working :)

```
x/dw 0x78B0E19c    --> Result 964
```

My find command was sth like this:

```
find 0x419a1000, 0x7e5b6000, 964
```

But I get as result these

```
0x419a3058
0x419a30c0
0x419a348c
0x419a3e7d
0x419a3fec
5 patterns found.
```

And this is not ture. It can t be possible that it is just within 5 addresses. It should be way more. It also seems that its not searching correctly. Because it just within the 0x419a3xxx range.

I am searching an int value within an arm architecture. But that point shouldn t matter. What I am doing wrong? Could you please provide me some examples to find all int values (964) within the address space of a process? And this pretty fast? :)

Thank you!

Comment: 1. For speed it does matter if you are debugging remotely. In this case try calling some function running on target, like memmem. Should be much faster. 2. As for only partial results being printed, I guess gdb can not search non-continuous memory blocks.